# Is there an abstraction for BitmapImage in .NET Core (coreclr)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core, coreclr

I would like to design a service that works with bitmaps, but I cannot find anything related with this kind of (common for GUIs) data structure.

Is there anything to work with them in a cross-platform way?

Comment: The answer is no they don't plan to support that yet. Wait.

Comment: Maybe it's better to use Streams?

Comment: What is your service supposed to do with bitmaps? If it just receives, stores and sends them, you could works with byte arrays containing encoded bitmap frames.

Comment: The service calls an API in a remote endpoint and it gives the results as a set of data + the resulting image. I would like consumers to avoid working with arrays and streams, but maybe it's the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.Drawing is now ported to .Net Core and there are a lot of third party library that is available [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/net-core-image-processing/).

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing in the BCL that directly supports this right now. You may be interested in ImageProcessorCore, which is a .NET Core-compatible library for loading and manipulating images of various formats.

https://github.com/jimbobsquarepants/imageprocessor

It is written with no native components, and therefore is portable to anywhere the framework runs.

Comment: For anyone looking at this answer, the project was rebranded to here: https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageSharp. Same stuff, just a different name.